# How can I find the users windows login username from ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, single-sign-on

I have an ASP.Net web application running on an IIS server, and I need to find the visitors login username.

How can I can find this? When testing locally it found my username using `new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());`, but it finds **NETWORK SERVICE** when running the app on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use forms authentication. Try:

```
User.Identity.Name
```